# Classify point size by attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, style

I use QGIS 2.14

I classified the colors of a point layer by one attribute, now I wanted to classify the size of each point in each category according to another attribute. I used the dialog "Data define override" and the Size assistant. Unfortunately the assistant only provides 5 classes, whereas I would need 10.

Is there a way to change the number of classes of the size assistant?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in both columns?

Comment: Why not use the expression builder instead of the size assistant? You can set the size to be a function of an attribute.